# Which Landsat version is appropriate to imply a supervised classification with GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, classification, landsat, land-classification

I need to imply a supervised classification with GRASS GIS to find build-up areas. 
I want to avoid Landsat 7 images due to SLC problem.

1. Can I use images of Landsat 8  or it's better to use images of Landsat 5?
2. Are images of Landsat 8 full operational or are they in calibration/test mode?
3. Which version is best supported from Grass GIS (6.4 or 7)?

Answer (score 1):

To decide if to use Landsat 8 or Landsat 5, consider the temporal coverage. If you want the recent state of build-up areas, use Landsat 8.

Images of Landsat 8 are fully operational but check the respective metadata.

You may use both GRASS GIS 6.4 or 7. But GRASS GIS 7 provides you with lots of nice new capabilities, for an overview see: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/